# Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception

Is there a way in C# to catch any kind of exception?
Like in C++ to catch any kind of exception
the format is like

```
try{
//Statements
}
catch(...){
// Some more statements
}
```

But this format in c# fails.
Help?

Comment: Consider **why** you want to catch any exception. Logging and rethrowing is a valid use case. But can you really write code to handle **any possible error** and allow your program to continue in a known state?

Comment: Actually, I use the open catch a lot at the root of my app so that I can restart it if an uncaught exception gets thrown.  This is great for services and the like.

Answer (score 7):

You can catch anything like :

```
catch {}
```

From .NET 2 and further, this is equivalent to:

```
catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Because every exception (even a Windows SEH exception) is guaranteed to be derived from `System.Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(VS.80).aspx) link out. It's all about exceptions.

What you are trying to do is use a [parameter-less catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(VS.80).aspx) like this:

```
try {
   // your code
} catch {
   // any exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // Statements
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Do stuff with ex
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

catch(Exception ex)

or catch()  <-- i believe the second one works

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework provides a mechanism to detect/handle run time errors. C# uses three keywords in exception handling: `try`, `catch`, `finally`. The `try` block contains the statement that can cause an exception. The `catch` block handles the exception, and the `finally` block is used for cleaning up.

```
try
{
//statements that can cause an exception
}
catch(Type x)
{
//statements for handling an exception
}
finally
{
//cleanup code
}
```